# How to get list of integers from input (without quotes) and use it in calculations

Tags: python, list, function

As you know input returns a string.

```
listOfNums = input("Type Numbers ")

def calcR(num1, num2):
    return 1 / ((1 / num1) + (1 / num2))
```

but here in reduce I need a list of numbers to place it in the function.

```
result = round(reduce(calcR, list(listOfNums)), 5)
```

If I run the app like that and type numbers in the input prompt I will have an error that tells me that you entered a string value and the function needs an integer value

Comment: Do you know how to split a string into a list of strings using a space delimiter? Do you know how to convert a string to an integer? Put those two things together.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `map`:

```py
from functools import reduce


listOfNums = input("Type Numbers ")
m = list(map(int, listOfNums))

def calcR(num1, num2):
    return 1 / ((1 / num1) + (1 / num2))

result = round(reduce(calcR, m), 5)
```